# Redux Saga, error swallowing

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I try to add a global error handler on my react app. That work perfecly but I have only one problem when I use saga and a fetch call. Below a simple example :

[image: example]

The error (in setModules) is swallowing (I think by the fetch promise) but I dont understand where and how to correct this behavior. Is this case, the error is never send to the error or unhandledrejection events and google devtool reports that error from the "getModules" function. I tried many changes (like using done instead of then and remove the catch) but no miracle.

Answer (score 0):

You have a catch statement into another catch... Try putting the (error handling logic) try/catch statement in your getModules saga **only** et viola.

I highly recommend to manage error into the sagas only, not in your gateways functions, that way to avoid this issues.

Comment: I have change this incorrect logic (thanks) fetch return a promise we dont need another one. But iit's seem to correct my behavior I need to use an undocumented put.sync instead a put. The main problem is when an error is throw since the saga generator is call.